# js google earth placemarks

Tags: javascript, google-earth

I am so lost.  I am trying to understand how to place placemarks into a global variable.

We have the following code:

```
// prepare placemark
    var placemark = earth.createPlacemark("");
    placemark.setName(PASSENGERS[i].name + " to " + PASSENGERS[i].house);

    // prepare icon
    var icon = earth.createIcon("");
    icon.setHref(url + "/img/" + PASSENGERS[i].username + ".jpg");

    // prepare style
    var style = earth.createStyle("");
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
    style.getIconStyle().setScale(4.0);

    // prepare stylemap
    var styleMap = earth.createStyleMap("");
    styleMap.setNormalStyle(style);
    styleMap.setHighlightStyle(style);

    // associate stylemap with placemark
    placemark.setStyleSelector(styleMap);

    // prepare point
    var point = earth.createPoint("");
    point.setAltitudeMode(earth.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    point.setLatitude(building.lat);
    point.setLongitude(building.lng);
    point.setAltitude(0.0);


    // associate placemark with point
    placemark.setGeometry(point);
```

we have a global variable called PASSENGERS

so I tried PASSENGERS[i].placemark =placemark; but i just get a null object.  I've tried console.log(placemark) but again I just get a null object.

Is placemark an object?  If it is how come I can't get any data, if it isn't what is it?
very confused. the google api documentation is hard to follow. help

Is placemark a function? but then why declare it as a var.  If it is a function how do I place it in PASSENGERS.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var placemark = earth.createPlacemark(PASSENGERS[i].ID);
```

From then on, you can reference the placemark using this

```
 var referencedPlacemark = earth.getElementById(ID);
```

The ID must be unique